# Javascript 'for of' loop not properly resolving to the value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a simple array that I'm trying to iterate over but I'm apparently not understanding the 'for of' JavaScript loop. The following code returns exactly has it should;

```
const callOBJb = ['KD0NBH0BJ','W0DLKOBJ','WA0TJTOBJ'];
        for (let i of callOBJb) {  
            console.log(i);
        }
```

return: KD0NBHOBJ W0DLKOBJ WA0TJTOBJ

But the following code errors out with; "TypeError: i.getCenter is not a function. (In 'i.getCenter()', 'i.getCenter' is undefined)" because the variable 'i' does not resolve to one of the above.

```
for (let i of callOBJb) {
       var Omiddle = i.getCenter(); 
    }
```

When I manually type the variable in such as;

```
var Middle = W0DLKOBJ.getCenter();
```

It works just fine. What am I not understanding about how this should work?
I don't think I can use the ForEach here at least I'm not having any more luck than the for...of.

I was asked what the resolved variable for W0DLKOBJ might look like.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(KD0NBHOBJ));
 {"_southWest":{"lat":39.204385,"lng":-94.60714},"_northEast":{"lat":39.20646,"lng":-94.60481}}
```

Comment: Your array contains strings. Strings don't have a `getCenter()` method. Why are you expecting this to work?

Comment: Use objecy in the array directly instead of string `const callOBJb = [KD0NBH0BJ,W0DLKOBJ,WA0TJTOBJ];`

Comment: In your last example `W0DLKOBJ` is the name of a variable, it's not a string. Don't quote the name when you're creating the array.

Comment: @barmar Its not really a string its a variable. As you say in the last note. I admit I didn't think of that.  But now have. See the next comment.

Comment: @Prakash_Sharma I tried that but I get 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: KD0NBH0BJ'  That variable is set, because when I hard code it into the algorithm it works.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser When you put it in quotes, it's a string.

Comment: You need to assign the variables before using them in the array. When you create the array, it gets the current values of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution came in how I received the data from PHP to start with. When I changed the definition to; `const callOBJb = <?php echo "[$callOBJb]" ?>` to include the square brackets and then used; `for (let val of callOBJb) {...etc` all of the variables resolved properly.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
var Middle = W0DLKOBJ.getCenter();
```

because this:

```
W0DLKOBJ
```

is different from this:

```
'W0DLKOBJ'
```

If the array should contain the variable values and not string literals, don't use quotes:

```
const callOBJb = [KD0NBH0BJ, W0DLKOBJ, WA0TJTOBJ];
```

Comment: OK, this I've now learned but it still doesn't work. The variable W0DLKOBJ won't resolve to its values unless I hard code it into the code i.e. var Omiddle = W0DLKOBJ.getCenter();  Any thought how to get it to resolve?

Comment: @KeithDKaiser: What do you mean by "won't resolve to its values"?  Can you update the question with an example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Technically I already gave the response it gives me. I get the error: "TypeError: i.getCenter is not a function. (In 'i.getCenter()', 'i.getCenter' is undefined)" I now understand that i.getCenter function will not work but if I understand correctly its because the 'I' won't resolve to W0DLKOBJ which is a variable of objects. But if I hard code W0DLKOBJ.getCenter that function works perfect. Its still a mystery to me why.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser: Try logging `i` to the console to see what it is.  Maybe you're creating the array before those objects are defined?  Without a more complete example all anybody can do is guess.  But if `i` doesn't have a function called `getCenter` then `i` doesn't have a function called `getCenter`.

Answer (score 1):

The `callOBJb` variable is an Array of strings, and when you use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement to perform a loop iteration, for each item in your iterable object you will get item at deposition corresponding to the time to loop bloc code is execute.

In you case as all items in the `callOBJb` array is simple string, javascript [`String.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) Object doesn't define a function named `getCenter` that is the reason why you are getting

> "TypeError: i.getCenter is not a function. (In 'i.getCenter()', 'i.getCenter' is undefined)

```js
let callOBJb = ['KD0NBH0BJ','W0DLKOBJ','WA0TJTOBJ'];

for(let item of callOBJb){
  console.log(typeof item, item);
}
```

As you can see on each iteration the `typeof item` is always string.

Comment: OK, I'm learning here, I'm learning. But how do I make my code work? Each of the strings i.e. 'W0DLKOBJ' is a variable and each individually work when I hard code them into "var Omiddle = W0DLKOBJ.getCenter();"

Comment: As all string the `callOBJb` variable represent an existing variable, you just remove the single quote around each String and that will work, You should ensure that you have predefine that variable before passing them to `callOBJb` like thos `let callOBJb  = [KD0NBH0BJ,W0DLKOBJ,WA0TJTOBJ]`

Answer (score 0):

I went back to the php and redesigned the output to make conversation to Javascript easier. By doing that I was able to iterate through the values using "for (let val of callOBJb)" successfully.